# Split points evenly to neighboring polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-join, point-in-polygon

I have a crime location data set, containing geocoded crime location points that have been geocoded to streets and street interactions. I also have a census tract shapefile. What I would like to do is to allocate these points to census tracts (polygons).

The problem is that many crime points fall right on or very close to the boundaries of tracts. I would like to split these points evenly to neighboring tracts.

For example, in the picture attached, there are 6 selected points right on or within 30 feet of the boundary of two tracts, I would like to count 3 points toward each tract.

[image]

Comment: Could you add some visuals?

Comment: a picture is added.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution using a certain GIS or just a generic approach?

Comment: what I have is ArcGIS 10.2.

Comment: When you say "allocate" the points, (1) is there a field such as "Tract_I_Belong_To" that identifies which tract a point belongs to? Or (2) do you want to physically move the points slightly so they are contained within a given polygon? What does "allocate" mean in your description?

Comment: If the purpose is to conduct statistical analysis relating crimes to tracts, consider instead *weighting* the points: you could assign a weight of 50% (for one tract) and 50% (for the other tract) to each one of those six points, rather than making a forced split into three and three.  Even that is probably not a great procedure, but what to recommend would depend on what kind of analysis you plan to do.

Comment: Proximity polygons and intersect with tracts Total fractions of polygon areas within tract